# How to render a name after clicking/tabbing out of a field in Django?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, ajax

I have a form that is used to keep track of when employees enter/leave an area to track times. The first field is where they enter their employee #. I have a table in my database that comes from another model, called *Salesman*, where all the employee data (names, dept., etc.) is stored, as shown here (only fields relevant to question shown):

**alldata/models.py**

```
class Salesman(models.Model):
    slsmn_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    id = models.IntegerField(db_column='number', primary_key=True)
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return ""
```

My model for the form is set so that the **employee_number** field is related to Salesman, so that the numbers entered in my form can only be numbers that are valid in Salesman based on the **id** and so that I can filter "who" can submit the form or not (depending on team/status).

**models.py**

```
class EmployeeWorkAreaLog(TimeStampedModel, SoftDeleteModel, models.Model):
    employee_number = models.ForeignKey(Salesman, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, help_text="Employee #", null=True, blank=False)
...
```

**forms.py**

```
class WarehouseForm(AppsModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EmployeeWorkAreaLog
        widgets = {
            'employee_number': ForeignKeyRawIdWidget(EmployeeWorkAreaLog._meta.get_field('employee_number').remote_field, site, attrs={'id':'employee_number_field'}),
        }
        fields = ('employee_number', 'work_area', 'station_number')

    def clean_employee_number(self):
        employee_number = self.cleaned_data.get('employee_number')
        if employee_number is None:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Must enter emp #")
        elif employee_number.team not in ('WF', 'WP', 'OM') or employee_number.employee_status not in 'A':
            raise forms.ValidationError("Employee not valid, please contact manager")
        return employee_number
```

What I need help with, is being able to render the name of the person in the html right on top of where they enter their employee # once they click away/tab out of the field, in the same way a "Username 'whatever' is taken" message shows after you type a username you want somewhere and once you go onto the next field, the page quickly cross-checks the db to see if the name exists and renders it.

I have no experience with AJAX/JS scripts/requests (and not much experience with python either, this has been figuring it out as I go), but I tried creating a function that returns the name from Salesman within views.py like this

```
def get_employee_name(request, id):
    employee = get_object_or_404(Salesman, id=id)
    return HttpResponse(employee.slsmn_name)
```

But I'm not sure how to get it to render/display within the HTML in my page. I was thinking maybe by checking if the length of the number entered is 6 then that triggers a request for the name (all employee numbers have 6 digits). Any guidance/advice on how to approach this is appreciated!

Comment: Are you using any JS framework already?

Answer (score 0):

Pass it thru a context dictionary.

```
def Detail(request, slug):
        employee = get_object_or_404(Salesman, id=id)
        context = {
            'employee' : employee,
        }
        return render(request, 'blog/blog_detail.html', context)
```

This is a view that returns an HTML template. 
[here is the docs for templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/templates/)

in the template, you can use the following to add the name.

```
<h1>{{employee.slsmn_name}}</h1>
```

Also As far as updating it once the put the number in. If you want it to update without sending another request you will have to use JS. I would suggest Vue.js as it is easy and works well within Django but pure js works great if you're worried about older browsers. For this functionality to work without ajax(i prefer axios for small apps) you will need to

1. pass the list of all employees thru a setter "onload" function
   attached to the body and store this list on the JS file.

2. Bind the input of the employee id to a variable in the js file
3. Sort through the list of employees to find the object that is a match.
4. Then bind the inner HTML of dom element that should contain the employee name and make innerhtml = name.

this makes it possible without an API call but if you have thousands of employees this will really slow down your site. This is pretty simple JS and does not require an advanced knowledge but is a great implementation of the fundamentals